Нет подключения к GitHub, выдает ответ Hi Tolmax! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access
При выполнении команды git push обновляется внешний репозиторий на Гитхабе.
При выполнении команды npm run deploy связи с сервером Гитхаб не происходит, получаю такой ответ.
Также получаю такой ответ при проверке - You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
В чем может быть проблема?


Почему не следует выкладывать код/данные/ошибки в виде скриншотов?

АП что за команда у вас в скрипте deploy-то?

А кириллица не виновата?

Скорее всего да, вы правы. я уже несколько раз удалил и создал ssh ключи.

В результате решил вопрос временно, поменяв code проверки с Гитхабом с ssh на HTTPS. Все стало работать. Вот тут нашел хорошую пошаговую инструкцию, как это сделать. https://sendel.ru/posts/https-to-ssh-on-github/

Пожалуйста, приложите основные цитаты/код, тк со временем ссылка может стать недоступной

Возможно, ssh-ключ с паролем, а при запуске команды его вводить некому.
